# Variadic pack expansion failure Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, variadic-templates

Below is code demonstrating a variety of parameter pack expansion scenarios. The scenario that fails is the expansion of `static const` members in a function within a template to yield a type: `using type = intco<funcplus(v_values::value...)>`. (However, the similar situation in which the result of the expansion defines an integral constant instead of a type succeeds, as indicated below.)

The code compiles successfully using Clang (Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)) and using GCC (gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005) but **fails** when using MSVC (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, v14.0.2531.01 update 3) with a warning "dependent name is not a type" followed by an error "syntax error : '...'".

Is there some compiler flag for MSVC that would resolve (or could be causing) this problem?

```
template<int t_value>
struct intco {
    static const int value = t_value;
};
template<int t_head, int... v_body>
struct structplus {
    static const int value = t_head + structplus<v_body...>::value;
};
template<int t_head>
struct structplus<t_head> {
    static const int value = t_head;
};
template<typename... v_values>
struct intco_structplus {
    //static const int value = structplus<v_values::value...>::value; //good
    using type = structplus<v_values::value...>; //good
    static const int value = type::value; //good
};
static_assert(6 == intco_structplus<intco<1>, intco<2>, intco<3>>::value, "1 + 2 + 3 ?= 6");
template<typename... v_ints>
constexpr int funcplus(int head, v_ints... v_body) {
    return head + funcplus(v_body...);
}
template<>
constexpr int funcplus<>(int head) {
    return head;
}
template<typename... v_values>
struct intco_funcplus {
    //static const int value = funcplus(v_values::value...); //good
    //static const int value = intco<funcplus(v_values::value...)>::value; //good
    using type = intco<funcplus(v_values::value...)>; //"dependent name is not a type"
    static const int value = type::value;
};
static_assert(6 == intco_funcplus<intco<1>, intco<2>, intco<3>>::value, "1 + 2 + 3 ?= 6");
```

Comment: looks like a bug... you could try using decltype e.g.: `using type = decltype(intco<funcplus(v_values::value...)>{});` to workaround

Comment: I'm not aware of any compiler flags that resolve this, you just have to poke the code a bit in arbitrary ways until msvc is placated afaik. there's not much rhyme or reason to which c++11 template constructions msvc accepts and which it doesn't

Comment: Thank you for the comments - I've submitted a bug report through the Visual Studio feedback and will update if I get a useful response. In the meantime the code above already shows a few possible work-arounds in case anyone else stumbles into this issue.